# Cosmos DB minimum partitions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventhub

We have a IoT scenario, with Azure Event Hub as our data ingestion service.Our proposed architecture is, we have a event capture (window = 15 mins) on the EH, use Azure Batch services to process the captured data at end of day/periodic intervals throughout the day and then store in a cold storage (blobs/Data lake).
We also want to have a pipeline of Event Hub -> Function App -> Cosmos DB, for instantaneous queries which may not be available through the event capture approach (as they won't be instantaneous).With respect to storage of cosmos db, we plan to have a ttl = 24/48 hrs. Now the problem is, if we opt for a partition of deviceId and above ttl we will not utilize the partition effectively (max = 10GB), and have multiple partitions which will impact cost.
So, my question is what other strategies(other db's/partitioning mechanisms) can we use to optimize(main concern - cost efficiency) database storage ?

1. Tried Single Partition collection - Wont be useful when to move to a higher scale of devices
2. Partitioning by time (hour/minutes), it would mean a pay-upfront model, which is not desired

Comment: having multiple logical partitions does not directly translate to multiple physical partitions. physical partitions are split either when your existing partition reach 10Gb storage  limit or when your physical partition reach throughput limit of 10000 RU/s per physical partition. `deviceId` is your first candidate for partition key. If you assume it would ever grow behind 10Gb per `deviceId` then introduce new property `partitionKey` (synthetic key) and make its value, for example, `$”device_{deviceId}_{month}”` or whatever is granular enough for you to never reach 10Gb limit.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you definitely need to partition your container. The deviceId would be a perfect match for a key, however I do get that you might fill up your partitions so you might look at a composite key. A composite key is a key that's consisted of two different properties of your document. In your case it could be `deviceId-somethingElse`. It would need to be a separate property in your documents, ideally called `partitionKey`, generated automatically by the values of your properties of choice.

Two things that I need to clear out which I think you don't quite understand correctly.

1. The number of partitions in Cosmos DB does not directly affect pricing. It indirectly affects it because after A LOT of data is stored in your system Cosmos will create more physical partitions which in return have a minimum amount of RU/s that they need provisioned each.
2. Data size affects the pricing so little that it's negligible.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your response.However i will have to disagree with your #2, i have had first hand experience of Data size indirectly affecting the cost in terms of Request charge for a query. Also could you be a little more specific with the parttionKey, the idea is to minimize the count of partitions.

Comment: Hello @AnirbanSinha. This is trust ONLY if you are using cross partition queries, which you should NEVER do as part of your application's normal workflow. Also on the partition minimization thing, you have to be very very careful, because the moment one partition is full you are done.

Comment: @AnirbanSinha you should not care about your number of logical partitions, especially not in a way to minimize their count. Quite the opposite, you should have as many logical partitions as possible to still keep related documents together in same logical partition for documents you need transactions. That way cosmos db will be very effective in hashing your keys & distributing both: storage and workload across physical partition and that will produce most cost effective outcome. Btw. date/time is rarely good partition key because it produces write hot spots.